# How to handle Mongoose document version Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting this error while updating the same document. I am continuously getting data from the socket and updates the document. But recent data was yet not updated and on socket emit updating new data on the same document. So how could I handle this error or wait for the callback for that document?

```
{ Error
at model.wrappedPointCut [as save] (/var/www/html/parcel-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/model/applyHooks.js:131:29)
at /var/www/html/parcel-app/server/server.js:372:22
at /var/www/html/parcel-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3115:18
at tryCatcher (/var/www/html/parcel-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/var/www/html/parcel-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:510:31)
at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/var/www/html/parcel-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:584:18)
at Promise._settlePromises (/var/www/html/parcel-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:700:14)
at Async._drainQueue (/var/www/html/parcel-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/var/www/html/parcel-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/var/www/html/parcel-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:733:5)
message: 'No matching document found for id "5ae99a15e5e73b39cacafe48"',
name: 'VersionError' }
```

Here is snippet

```
  socket.on('sendUserLocation', function(data) {
  //when app send new location of user this method will invoked
  if (data !== undefined) {
    var lat = data.lat;
    var lng = data.lng;
    var userType = data.user_type;
    var roomName = data.room_name;
    var heading = data.heading != undefined ? data.heading : 0;

    if (userType == 'db') {
      var returnBoj = {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        user_type:'db',
        room_name: roomName,
        heading: heading, //heading is degree of db boy which will -180-0-180
      };
      //finding user by room id which is user document id mongoose
      DeliveryboyModel.findById(roomName).exec(function (err, DBData) {
        if (DBData) {
          locationArray = [ parseFloat(lat) , parseFloat(lng) ];
          DBData.locationDetails.location = locationArray;
          DBData.save(function (err) {
             //getting error here
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          });
        }
      });

      // emmiting addnewmarker so customer app will get new location and will update pin to new location
      socket.emit('addnewmarker', returnBoj);
      socket.broadcast.to(roomName).emit('addnewmarker', returnBoj);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Same error showing at my end. please help me

Comment: need more same code

Comment: Provide schema and code snippet from where are trying to create

Comment: Can you provide your order of operation followed? Its impossible to reproduce the issue with the provided description.

Comment: @RitwickDey added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is hinting it cannot find the document, so if it's a native query try wrapping it with `ObjectId`, ie `ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011")`.

To answer your question as to how you can wait for the document or handle the error depends upon your db driver. For instance, if you are using promised-mongo:

```
db.collection.update(...).then((doc) => {
  // This will run once updated
}).catch((err) => { //handle the error});
```

read more: https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo

Or if you're using the mongodb npm module:

```
db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId('yourId'), {updateKey: 
'updateVal}, (err,val) => {
  if(err) //handle it and return
  // update finished
  return callback(doc);
});
```

more details at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

If the problem still exists, try setting the query with a flag `{upsert: true}`, as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

Keep in mind incoming socket messages might not always arrive in the same order they were sent, handle the state appropriately or use a queue.

Comment: yes it works !! Updated to Promise based query with => operator. Now not throwing an error.